# Paperclip generating extra file in root of Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have a controller method which receives a string from the client, converts it to a pseudo file using `StringIO`, and saves as a [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) attribute.

```
#tasks_controller
def generate 
    generator = StringIO.new(params[:generator])
    @task.update_attribute :generator, generator

    render nothing: true
end
```

This does save the string as a file in the correct location, but additionally saves the same file under a random hexadecimal name in the root directory of the rails app.

Here is the task object defining where the paperclip attribute should be saved:

```
#task.rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :generator, :url => "/generators/:id/generator.js"
end
```